# Consecutive calls to stack throws RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size

Tags: python, pytorch

I think both `torch.cat` and `torch.stack` cannot fully satisfy my requirement.

Initially, I define an empty tensor. Then I want to append a 1d-tensor to it for multiple times.

```
x = torch.tensor([]).type(torch.DoubleTensor)
y = torch.tensor([ 0.3981,  0.6952, -1.2320]).type(torch.DoubleTensor)
x = torch.stack([x,y])
```

This will throw an error:

> RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [0] at entry 0 and [3] at entry 1

So I have to initialise `x` as `torch.tensor([0,0,0])` (but can this be avoided?)

```
x = torch.tensor([0,0,0]).type(torch.DoubleTensor)
y = torch.tensor([ 0.3981,  0.6952, -1.2320]).type(torch.DoubleTensor)
x = torch.stack([x,y])  # this is okay
x = torch.stack([x,y])  # <--- this got error again
```

But when I run `x = torch.stack([x,y])` the second time, I got this error:

> RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [2, 3] at entry 0 and [3] at entry 1

What I want to achieve is being able to append a 1d-tensor multiple times (the added 1d-tensor is different at each time, here I use the same one for simplicity)**:

```
tensor([[ 0.3981,  0.6952, -1.2320],
        [ 0.3981,  0.6952, -1.2320],
        [ 0.3981,  0.6952, -1.2320],
        [ 0.3981,  0.6952, -1.2320],
        ...
        [ 0.3981,  0.6952, -1.2320]], dtype=torch.float64)
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: using a list would of course doable, but it needs me to write more code, convert to list and convert back to tensor.

Comment: can you write down your answer? I am not quite following what you said.

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted to stack vectors with different number of elements, e.g., `[n]`, where `n` would be sometimes 3, but could also be something else. Nevermind. Your problem was much simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of torch.cat "All tensors must either have the same shape (except in the concatenating dimension) or be empty".  So, the easiest solution is to add one more dimension (size 1) to the tensor you want to add.  Then, you will have tensors of size (n, whatever) and (1, whatever) which will be concatenated along the 0th dimension, meeting the requirements for torch.cat.

Code:

```
x = torch.empty(size=(0,3))
y = torch.tensor([ 0.3981,  0.6952, -1.2320])
for n in range(5):
    y1 = y.unsqueeze(dim=0) # same as y but with shape (1,3)
    x = torch.cat([x,y1], dim=0)
print(x)
```

Output:

```
tensor([[ 0.3981,  0.6952, -1.2320],
        [ 0.3981,  0.6952, -1.2320],
        [ 0.3981,  0.6952, -1.2320],
        [ 0.3981,  0.6952, -1.2320],
        [ 0.3981,  0.6952, -1.2320]])
```